# AngularJS nested views not showing when using angular route segment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, url-routing

I am using nested views in a mobile app.  I am trying to use this module:

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-route-segment

But i can see the templates getting loaded via XHR but nothing appears on page.

I am not sure that the controllers are being loaded either, the example app seems to mix passing the controller reference as a string or by reference.

I tried using UI-router with more success but it no longer seems to support animated views with the latest RC of AngularJS which is something i have to have in my app.

This is my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('HealIntApp', ['ngRoute', 'angular-carousel', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'route-segment', 'view-segment']);

app.config(['$routeSegmentProvider', '$routeProvider', function($routeSegmentProvider, $routeProvider){

    $routeSegmentProvider.options.autoLoadTemplates = true;

    $routeSegmentProvider
    .when('/', 'index')
    .when('/setup/charting', 'setup.charting')
    .when('/setup/contacts', 'setup.contacts')
    .when('/setup/medical', 'setup.medical')
    .when('/setup/ready', 'setup.ready')
    .when('/setup/gps', 'setup.gps')
    .when('/setup/net', 'setup.net')
    .when('/setup/settings', 'setup.settings')
    .segment('index', {
        templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/main.html',
        controller: 'CtrlMain'
    })
    .within()
        .segment('setup', {
            templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/setup.html',
            controller: 'CtrlSetup'
        })
        .within()
            .segment('charting', {
                templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/setup.charting.html'
            })
            .segment('contacts', {
                templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/setup.contacts.html',
                controller: 'CtrlSetupContacts'
            })
            .segment('medical', {
                templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/setup.medical.html',
                controller: 'CtrlSetupMedical'
            })
            .segment('ready', {
                templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/setup.ready.html',
                controller: 'CtrlSetupReady'
            })
            .segment('gps', {
                templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/setup.gps.html'
            })
            .segment('location', {
                templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/setup.location.html'
            })
            .segment('net', {
                templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/setup.net.html'
            })      
            .segment('settings', {
                templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/setup.settings.html',
                controller: 'CtrlSetupSettings'
            });

}]);
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" lang="en" ng-app="HealIntApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lib/pure-0.2.1.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lib/font-awesome.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lib/angular-carousel.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
        <title>HealInt</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u-1" app-view-segment="index">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/lib/cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/angular-1.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/angular-mobile.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/angular-touch.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/angular-route-segment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/angular-carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app/factory/cordova-ready.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app/controllers/main-ctrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app/controllers/setup-ctrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app/controllers/setup-ready-ctrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app/controllers/setup-settings-ctrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app/controllers/setup-contacts-ctrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app/controllers/setup-medical-ctrl.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My main.html partial that should be pulled into the DOM at the root URL:

```
<div class="pure-u-1">
    <a href="#/setup" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Setup</a>
</div>
```

And the associated controller that logs nothing:

```
app.controller('CtrlMain', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    console.log('main controller loaded');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use segment name, use segment index number.
Example:

```
<div class="pure-u-1" app-view-segment="0"></div>
```

if you need nested route, use app-view-segment="1" and so on.

Comment: What if you have both nested and non-nested routes. Then what? How do you get the current app-view-segment index?